# CP2K Spherical Cell

Tags: cp2k, periodic-boundary-conditions

I'm trying to run a gas phase cluster calculation in CP2K. I want to create an outside force to constrain water molecules that are in the simulation within a radius of a central ion. I want to create a spherical cell of a given radius , fix the ion in the center and then run QMMD with the waters free to do their motion.

Does anyone know how to create a spherical cell for the simulation with no periodic boundary conditions or a better way to impose this clustering constraint ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose of the sphere (perhaps by editing the question)? Is this sphere intended just as a way to guide the construction of the initial atomic configuration or is it supposed to play a role during the simulation as well?

Comment: Hi dtg67, can you try to answer @leopold.talirz's question? Otherwise we might have to close this as an "abandoned" question.